# CSS is not affecting the <span> tag

Tags: html, css

In my CSS, it is not affecting my `span` tags, I've tried a lot and can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

*sorry I realize "it's not working" is vague. The css is just not applying.

```css
.buttonContainer span.mySpan {
  margin-left: 3%;
  font-size: 3vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #A8A8A8;
}

.buttonContainer span.mySpan:hover {
  color: #F7BE33;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #F7BE33;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <span class='mySpan' onmouseenter="openNavAbout()" onmouseleave="closeNavAbout()">&#9776;About us</span>
  <span class='mySpan' onmouseover="openNavTS();" onmouseout="closeNavTS();">&#9776;Team Structure</span>
  <span class='mySpan' onmouseover="openNavSE();" onmouseout="closeNavSE();">&#9776;Sustainability Efforts</span>
  <span class='mySpan' onmouseover="openNavTM();" onmouseout="closeNavTM();">&#9776;Team Members</span>
</div>
```

It works if I apply style directly to the spans, so it is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Putting your code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gtgnyrb2/ . ; Can you tell what's not working?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me

Comment: If your css is in a stylesheet then it is probably not located. Your browser's developer tools will tell you.

Comment: Works fine though I am curious why you're adding such specificity to your declaration as `span.mySpan`. If you're going to declare a class; why also declare the element?

Comment: @AndyG This isn't the case because I have about 500 lines not included that the CSS does apply to.

Comment: Then you may need to clear your browser's cache for recent changes to be applied.

Comment: ?? am I the only one here seeing references to javascript functions that are not declared?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini The question is not about the JavaScript.

Comment: well, the CSS is working just fine

Comment: "It works if I apply style directly to the spans" suggests that the OP is using a stylesheet and it is this that is the problem.

Comment: @AndyG clearing the cache worked! Although I'm not sure why, can you explain? Also why is a stylesheet a problem.

Comment: The browser retains a copy of the stylesheet in its browser's cache, and won't update it automatically - unless you take steps to cause this to happen. The browser was still using this earlier copy of your file.

Comment: For testing purposes it's nice to add pragma no cache headers, it makes life easier than constantly clicking ctrl+h. 2c.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added some rules to an attached stylesheet and they aren't taking effect then it is most likely that the browser is still referencing an earlier version of your CSS file, held in its browser's cache.

To resolve this, clear your browser's cache. There is also generally a setting with the browser's developer tools to enable always fetching the most recent copy of the file; that is, not to cache the file(s).